# How do i use conditional formatting based on date and other cells in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

I want to make cell A with yellow when the date from this cell is less with two days than today and only when cell C or B are empty, and cell A to be with red when the date is less with two days than today and both cells C and B are empty. What formula should i use in conditional formatting ?

This formula is working : if(and(a1<=today()-2,b1128=""),1,0)
But i would like if its possible to calculate only the working days.
Could someone give me a idea ?

@Emily : 7/5/2021 - 2 working days = 7/1/2021. So i need to mark only the 7/1/2021 and the oldest dates in this case. In this -2 days i want to add also the weekend days if is the case ... For eg. 7/2/2021 to be marked only in 7/6/2021

if the date is on Friday i want to be marked only on Tuesday... To skip the weekend days. If is on Monday to be marked on Wednesday

@Emily : the last one's are not working at all, i dont know why ...
Actually is working only for 7/2/2021

@Emily : Yes, in your table is the correct information just with mention that i need to mark also the older dates : eg. On Monday i need to mark last Wednesday and all dates that are older than last Wednesday ... On Tuesday i need to mark last Thursday and all dates that are older than last Thursday ... And so on ...

Comment: You should provide an numerical example.  What have you tried?  The AND command allows you to achieve multiple test conditions.

Comment: Hi @PRADAN ADRIAN ,, if you wanna to respond any of the posts then use comments rather than add your views with original post !!

Comment: Check your post & better [edit] since for both RED & Yellow you have same criteria **"date is less with two days than today and both cells C and B are empty"** !!

Comment: Yellow when C or B and red when both of them are empty and yea, same criteria less with two days then today and to skip the weekend days ( if its friday to be marked only on tuesday )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your explaination, I would update my reply as following.

According to your description, it seems that you need to get following results. Any misunderstanding, you may tell me.

[image]

Highlight cell A with Red：

`=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)>3,AND(A1<=TODAY()-3,B1&C1=""),AND(A1<=TODAY()-5,B1&C1=""))`

Highlight cell A with Yellow:

`=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)>3,AND(A1<=TODAY()-3,B1<>"",C1=""),AND(A1<=TODAY()-5,B1<>"",C1=""))`

`=IF(WEEKDAY(TODAY(),2)>3,AND(A1<=TODAY()-3,B1="",C1<>""),AND(A1<=TODAY()-5,B1="",C1<>""))`

Please also pay attention to the application range of these formulas.

[image]

Comment: From you eg. 7/2/2021 should be not with yellow because 7/5/2021 - 2 working days = 7/1/2021. So i need to mark only the 7/1/2021 and the oldest dates in this case. In this -2 days i dont want to count the weekend days ... For eg. 7/2/2021 to be marked only in 7/6/2021

Comment: The point is that if the date is on Friday i want to be marked only on Tuesday... To skip the weekend days. If is on Monday to be marked on Wednesday

Comment: @PRADANADRIAN You need to add your comments to the original question.

Comment: Thank you but these formulas are working only for 7/2/2021

Comment: @PRADANADRIAN Does this "two days" include "today"? One example " 7/5/2021 - 2 working days = 7/1/2021. So i need to mark only the 7/1/2021", "two days" here includes the day of 7/5/2021. But another one "If is on Monday to be marked on Wednesday", it excludes the day of Monday self. If based on this description, 7/5/2021 - 2 working days = 6/30/2021.

Comment: You are right. Today should not be included in this "two days".

Comment: @PRADANADRIAN I have modified my reply again, you may have a check.

Comment: Yes, in your table is the correct information just with mention that i need to mark also the older dates : eg. On Monday i need to mark last Wednesday and all dates that are older than last Wednesday ... On Tuesday i need to mark last Thursday and all dates that are older than last Thursday ... And so on

Comment: Do conditions that B or C is empty, both B, C are empty apply to these older dates? If yes,   you may add "<" in formulas. I updated my previous reply.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!